# JHipster - Run spring boot with mvnw command

Tags: java, postgresql, jhipster

I am using a JHipster to create a spring boot application with PostgreSQL.

Actualy, when i execute the command mvnw the application-dev config file is "cleaned" to the initial properties.

```
datasource:
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource    
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
username: test
password:
```

In this case, my database properties (user, password ...) are cleaned. I obtain the error:

> "2017-08-06 18:17:10.726 ERROR 10844 --- [  restartedMain]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
>   during pool initialization.
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based
>   authentication, but no password was provided."

Anyone can help me?

Comment: where's your password?

Comment: I added allways the password in  application-dev file. When i run the command the password, and emails configurations (for example) are cleaned.

Comment: Did you save the file after making the changes?  It's not normal for `mvnw` to clear your config changes

Comment: yes, i save the file. The same happens when I build on netbeans. When you start the build and the file clears automatically

Comment: have you checked the active profile in log? Does it match the application-<profile>.yml file?

Answer (score 0):

Need to put password into password .

```
datasource:
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource    
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
username: test
password:<YOUR PASSWORD>
```

Comment: I know this, I put password in these place. WHen i run the mvnw command this password is cleaned, allways cleaned.